# How to remove file extension using C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove file extension of a file with many dots in it:

```
string a = "asdasdasd.asdas.adas.asdasdasdasd.edasdasd";

string b = a.Substring(a.LastIndexOf('.'), a.Length - a.LastIndexOf('.'));

string c = a.Replace(b, "");

Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Googling this exact question title yields [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7356223/1188513) as the first search result...

Comment: are you doing this for practice?

Comment: Please people, for the next time don't answer this question, close it for migratation. This site is codereview, not stackoverflow.

Comment: Can `a` contain a path?

Comment: @Manu343726 I don't really like this question, but it does not need to be migrate IMO. We should migrate good question, not borderline question.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. Consider `a = "a.a.a"` which should output `"a.a"` but actually returns `a`.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a poor question for Code Review. However, it's technically on-topic according to our rules. It should stay open, but feel free to upvote/downvote according to your opinion.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you can, just use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns the file name of the specified path string without the extension.

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("asdasdasd.asdas.adas.asdasdasdasd.edasdasd");
```

With one line of code you can get the same result.

If you want to create one by yourself, why not just use this?

```
int index = a.LastIndexOf('.');
b = index == -1 ? a : a.Substring(0, index);
```

P.S Special thanks to @Anthony and @CompuChip to point me out some mistake i done, bad day maybe.

You take everything which comes from 0 (the start) to the last dot which means the start of the extension

Comment: Just note that `b = a.Substring(0, a.LastIndexOf('.'));` will break on files without an extension because it will end up calling `a.Substring(0, -1)`.

Comment: @Anthony Fixed :)

Comment: And saving a call to `Substring` when it is unnecessary:

`b = index == -1 ? a : a.Substring(0, index);`

Comment: Thanks to you too @CompuChip, would be great to give to you an upvote but... :|

Comment: No problem, I'm just happy to help. I wouldn't call it a mistake either - your original code did the job as well and to be honest I don't think the difference would be noticeable in practice. Just think this is a bit more readable.

Comment: It's important to note that `Path.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` removes the path portion of the input. e.g. `Path.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("a\b.c")` returns `"b"` not `"a\b"`.

Comment: Also note that the `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` is slower as it checks for invalid path chars and try to extract the `DirectorySeparatorChar`, `AltDirectorySeparatorChar` or `VolumeSeparatorChar` in a **loop** which seems not necessary for file names (not full path's)!

Comment: I just found an issue where Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension doesn't work on file names containing the colon (:) character. This character is not permitted in Windows file names, but we've got some integration code using FTP servers that have file names with colons in them. 
"abc:def.exe" returns "def", instead of "abc:def"

Answer (score 12):

Use the Path class within the namespace `System.IO`.

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code, you are getting the subsection of the extension, then removing it from the original. Instead you should simply just get the subsection of the string without the extension.

```
string c = a.Substring(0, a.LastIndexOf('.'));
```

**Edit**: Just as stated before me by Marco :D

Comment: Downvoted, why?

Comment: What happens if the filename doesn't have any `.extension`?

Comment: @200_success It borks, however the parameter of this question is that this path has multiple dots in it. I simply took shortcuts to improve the posted code. I did not go into depth about error checking.